# Unable to fit data due to "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'" error

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, data-fitting, function-fitting

I'm trying to fit and plot a simple data in a .txt file with a linear function `(a*x+b)` using matplotlib and scipy. I run into an error concerning the test function: `"can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'"`

I have tried changing the variable name `x` but I get the same problem. Most of the code comes from a working one that is able top fit data without problems and uses the same definition for the test function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np
f=open("testData.txt","r")
x_data=[]
y_data=[]
trash=f.readline() #discards first line
for line in f: #reads x and y data from file
    x_read,y_read=line.split()
    x_data.append(float(x_read))
    y_data.append(float(y_read))

def test_func(x, a, b):
    return a*x+b

params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data, 
p0=[1, 1])
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
plt.plot(x_data, test_func(x_data, params[0], params[1]), label='Fitted 
function')
plt.show()
```

This is the error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Fra/Desktop/lab/ottica/2/reaqd.py", line 19, in 
>       plt.plot(x_data, test_func(x_data, params[0], params[1]), label='Fitted function')
>
> File "C:/Users/Fra/Desktop/lab/ottica/2/reaqd.py", line 14, in test_func
>       return a*x+b
>
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Comment: Turn your lists into numpy ndarrays before passing them to test_func.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably trying to multiply a Python list by a float, which does not work. Try `a*np.array(x)+b`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I don't quite get why it works, shouldn't the "x" variable behave like a float?

Comment: @FrancescoPettini no, in your code `x` is a Python list. Multiplication of Python lists by floats is not defined, since they can contain arbitrary objects (not just numbers).

Comment: Note that this is slower than changing the initial list into a numpy array directly, before fitting and plotting. Now, every time the function is called, the list is changed into a NumPy array, with all the overhead. For hard (read: slow) to fit functions and large lists, this may slow down things noticeably.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking about how the accepted answer works, showing the "old-school" way may have its use:

```
plt.plot(x_data, 
  [test_func(x, params[0], params[1]) for x in x_data],
  label='Fitted function')
```

`x_data = []` is clearly a list, and as Python is not Matlab, `number*x_data` is not an element-wise multiplication, but creates a list which repeats `x_data`, `number` times, which needs an integer.